# Como encontrar el valor de un dato en un array solo conociendo su posición sin usar array list JAVA

Tags: java, array

Hola estoy aprendiendo sobre arrays en Java y estoy estancado en un ejercicio.

Necesito saber el valor de un elemento contenido en un array basado su posición sin usar Arraylist.

Por ejemplo,
En un array de 10 posiciones llamado modelRemuneration encontrar el valor que se encuentra en la posición 5, esta posición sería indicada con una variable int maximumLimit=5;

Esto es lo que he intentado hacer:

```
int maximumLimit=5;

for(int i=0;i<modelRemuneration.length;i++) {
    if(modelRemuneration[i]==maximumLimit[i]) {
       maximumLimit=i;
    }
}
```

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar.... Gracias.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta. Si lo que necesitas es acceder a la posición 5 de tu array modelRemuniretion solo haz esto "modelRemuniretion[5]". Si por el contrario no es acceder a la posición 5, por favor, aclara un poco el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Obtienes los valores dentro del array mediante su indice**, por ejemplo para obtener el valor de un array con indice 2:

```
  int[] modelRemuneration = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
  int i = 2;
  int valor =  modelRemuneration[i];
  System.out.println(valor);
```

en este caso la salida sería:

```
3
```

si deseas comparar el valor del array con determinado indice (`modelRemuneration[i]`) con el de la variable `maximumLimit` debes realizarlo de esta forma

```
 if(modelRemuneration[i]==maximumLimit) {
```

por lo tanto tu código debería ser:

```
 int[] modelRemuneration = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

 int maximumLimit=5;

 for(int i=0;i<modelRemuneration.length;i++) { 
     if(modelRemuneration[i]==maximumLimit) { 
        maximumLimit=i;
     }
 }

 System.out.println("el limite maximo es: " + maximumLimit);
```